# Selecting HTML elements from Ajax GET response with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, express

I am a programming student, I'm trying to build a simple website using HTML, JavaScripts, and jQuery for the front-end, and node.js + Express frameworks for the back-end.

In this example, I am using Ajax to get data, then append HTML codes + this data to a div element with the id = 'listFile'. The implementation works fine, I am able to see the Download and Delete button appended by Ajax.

However, when I used jQuery id selector to select the delete button and make an alert, it did not work at all. It seems I cannot select the delete button implemented by Ajax.

Please explain for me why this happen, and how to fix it. Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/download',
    method: "get",
    success: function(data){
        for(i=1; i<data.length; i++){
            $('#listFile').append("<tr><td id='tab'><a href='#' class='list-group-item' id='"+data[i]+"' style='margin-top:5px' value='"+data[i]+"'>"+data[i]+"</a></td><td id='tab2' ><a href='#' style='width:90px' id='deleteButton' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a><a href='#' style='width:90px' id='downloadButton' class='btn btn-primary'>Download</a</td></tr>");
        }   
    }
});

$('#deleteButton').click(function(){
    alert("DELETED");
});
```

Comment: You will have to do it like this `$(document).on("click",'#deleteButton',function(){alert("DELETED");});`

Comment: You have about 3 different problems in your code buddy, Unfortunately every answer here spotted only one.

Comment: 1) use classes for the delete buttons instead of IDs
2) use jQuery .on() instead of .click()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `click` binding like below:

```
$(document).on('click', '#deleteButton',function(){
   alert("DELETED");
});
```

**Explanation:** `$('#deleteButton').click` event will work only for available DOM element when window load successfully. As Delete button is created dynamically using ajax so you should use `$(document).on('click', '#deleteButton',function(){` so that it works for current available DOM elements

**Suggestion:** Should use `.` **class** for multiple delete buttons instead of `#` **id** and change binding code to `.deleteButton` from `#deleteButton`

Comment: wow, amazing! It finally works! I have been going crazy at this for almost 2 hours not understanding why it won't work. Thanks a lot Manesh.

Comment: Also, very simple and helpful explanation!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/download',
        method: "get",
        success: function(data){
            for(i=1; i<data.length; i++){
                $('#listFile').append("<tr><td id='tab'><a href='#' class='list-group-item' id='"+data[i]+"' style='margin-top:5px' value='"+data[i]+"'>"+data[i]+"</a></td><td id='tab2' ><a href='#' style='width:90px' id='deleteButton' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a><a href='#' style='width:90px' id='downloadButton' class='btn btn-primary'>Download</a</td></tr>");
            }   
 xyz();
        }

    });
    function xyz(){
       $('#deleteButton').click(function(){
           alert("DELETED");
       });
    }
```

Comment: What would it help to make it into a function. that is not the problem

Comment: it will help. let him check.

Comment: Wrong, the problem is the click event.

Comment: you should call that xyz() inside success function

Comment: sorry I forgot that

Comment: Hi @Suresh, I just tried your code. Now the buttons are disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about having the ".click" method bound to the new item you created. .click is setup to look at the dom on first load but will not attach any newly created buttons to the click event. By using ".on" you are telling your script to look at whatever you are targeting and then attach whatever event to it.

```
$(".container").on("event",".target",function(){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery selector is based on an id of "deleteButton."  ID's should be unique within a document but your code will generate multiple links with ID=deleteButton.

Consider adding a class to your delete button and then using that as the selector:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/download',
    method: "get",
    success: function(data){
        for(i=1; i<data.length; i++){
            $('#listFile').append("<tr><td id='tab'><a href='#' class='list-group-item' id='"+data[i]+"' style='margin-top:5px' value='"+data[i]+"'>"+data[i]+"</a></td><td id='tab2' ><a href='#' style='width:90px' id='deleteButton-"+data[i]+"' class='deleteButton btn btn-danger'>Delete</a><a href='#' style='width:90px' id='downloadButton' class='btn btn-primary'>Download</a</td></tr>");
        }   
    }
xyz();
});
function xyz(){
   $('.deleteButton').click(function(){
       alert("DELETED");
   });
}
```

Note that I've added a class and changed the id of each element in your list to be unique by appending data[i] to its ID.  Note that I've also changed the "#" in your jQuery selector to "." - this changes the selector from finding element with id=deleteButton to finding element with class=deleteButton.

Once you've detected that click, it's then easy to capture the id of the specific item that's being clicked using $(this).attr('id').

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Event Delegation**. This means that instead of attaching the click event on the `delete` button itself, you attach it on any of its ascendent. Now whenever the button is clicked, due to the `Event Bubbling` process, the event is moved all the way up to the DOM. As soon as the event reaches the target element which was listening for that event, it will execute the code that you wrote.

Enough talk, here's how you can do it:

```
$('document').on("click", ".deleteButton" function() {
    alert("DELETED");
});
```

Note that I've replaced the `#deleteButton` with `.deleteButton` since an `ID` MUST be unique throughout the document, therefore, you must replace the replace the html markup `<button id='deleteButton'>` with `<button class='deleteButton'>` in the `append` method.

There are a couple of more things that you should note down.

1. Once your ajax request has completed. You are jumping into the DOM to select the element with the `ID` of `#listFile` which is being done inside a loop which is really bad for performance issues.

**Solution**
Store the: element reference before you execute the loop.

```
success: function() {
    var listFile = $('#listFile');
    for (...) {
        listFile.append(....)
    }
}
```

2. Instead of appending the elements inside a loop which will cause the DOM 
   to reflow every single time you append an element, consider using `DocumentFragment`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment

Hope that makes sense, feel free to ask any questions! :-)

Comment: Thanks for noting me about the performance issues with my code, and provide a solution for it! I am very new to programming, yet my course requires me to learn and use JavaScript, Jquery, Ajax, MongoDb, Express, and Node.js all at the same time for a single project. So I don't have a lot of time and resources to learn carefully about how each one of those works.
I appreciate your well written response a lot!